# python - set value with if statement

Tags: python, arrays, indexing

I have a chart with some rows have no value.I want it to take the value of previous row. Something like below:

```
for index, item in enumerate(df4.Settle):
    if (item == 'No value'):
        item = item[index-1] #<--I want to do this
```

How to do that?

Comment: Is your code working or not?

Comment: You just post some code and say *"I do the following... how to do that?"*?

Comment: You need to replace `item[index-1]` by `df4.Settle[index-1]`, but that won't work if you have two times `'No value'` in a row.

Comment: @S4M It will because he's updating the 'No value's as he goes through the list

Comment: @Dashiell No it won't, because the enumeration he is working on will be immutable inside the loop.

Comment: In order for this particular to work, it'll need to be converted into a while loop, and also decrement the `index` counter when it incurs a 'No value'.

Comment: My mistake, I was assuming OP wanted to *update* his original list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't exactly understand what you want to do. The sample you provided doesn't make much sense because

```
>> item == 'no value'  # that's your condition
>> item[index-1] in 'no value' # item[index-1] in 'no value'  
True                           # will be true for any valid int
```

But I think you want something like this:

```
>>> lst = [[1,2,3], 'No value', [0,0,0]]
>>> for index, item in enumerate(lst):
...   if item == 'No value':
...     lst[index] = lst[index-1]
... 
>>> lst
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple error in the third line. Your code should instead read

```
for index, item in enumerate(df4.Settle):
  if (item == 'No value'):
    item = df4.Settle[index-1]
```

Originally you were taking a character from the word "No value", whereas now you will be taking the value from the data table. I should point out this will cause an error if your first value is "No value".

Comment: This won't work because you're assigning item to a new variable but you never actually make it part of the list :)

Comment: @joaquinlpereyra OP never said that he wants to change the list.

Comment: 'I have a chart with some rows have no value.I want it to take the value of previous row. ' I assume 'it' must refer to the chart which consists of rows.

Comment: @joaquinlpereyra That doesn't necessarily mean that he wants to change the list. Maybe he just wants to change the value of the `item` variable and do some other stuff with it.

Comment: Your interpretation could make sense. Anyhow, we'll just let OP decide what he wants to do :)

Answer (score 0):

There's the special `NoneType` with its only instance `None` to represent empty values in python.
Furthermore it is not clear what you want to do with the respective values from the *chart* thingy.
So assuming you want to iterate over them using `None` instead of your string `'No value'`:

```
def yield_or_previous(iterable):
    last_item = None

    for item in iterable:

        if item is not None:
            last_item = item
            yield item
        else:
            if last_item is not None:
                yield last_item
            else:
                # TODO: What shall be done if first item is None?
                # Raise an exception?
                #raise ValueError('First item must not be none')
                # or pass?
                pass

# Call it
for item in yield_or_previous(df4.Settle):
    # Do whatever
    print(item)
```